# How to define two depend classes?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

take a look at following simple code :

```
class A;
class B
{
    A a;
};

class A
{
    B b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 1;
}
```

it does not compile, why ?

*Error Message from GCC (Qt):* 
**main.cpp:6: error: field ‘a’ has incomplete type**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well that's impossible since A would contain a B which would contain an A etc.
if they depend on eachother they could hold references or pointers to eachother or one could hold the other whilst the other holded a pointer/reference.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, if you *define* an object of some kind, it must be a complete type, otherwise its size wouldn't be known and the layout of the `struct` which would contain it couldn't be known.

Moreover the thing you wrote makes no sense, because if you wanted to create an object of type `A`, it would include an object of type `B`, which would contain an object of type `A`, and so on. Thus, an object of type `A` or of type `B` would take infinite space in memory, which is definitely not good.

Instead, if those members were pointers/references the forward declarations would suffice and you wouldn't even have this "little" problem of requiring infinite memory for a structure. :)

Answer (score 2):

In order for the compiler to be able to build class `B` it needs to know the size of all its members. Forward declaration `class A;` does not tell that, only introduces the name `A` into the scope. You can use a **pointer** or a **reference** to `A`, the size of which compiler always knows.

Answer (score 1):

You must make at least one of them a pointer. Otherwise, you are asking each instance to allocate an instance of the other class. In other words, you are asking it to allocate an infinte amount of memory:

Answer (score -1):

you cannot have A a. You have forward declared A, you cannot use it until you define it.